# tabular/stackengine: How to exceed/clobber row or cell frame

Tags: tables, stackengine

I have a table where some cells may contain an additional qualifier element right above their contents.

Imagine 3 houses and their owners at certain points in time. Some owners may be related to previous owners as marked in the example below.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{rccc}
  Year & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \hline
  1810 & John Doe & John Deere & John Denver \\
  1820 &  &  &  \\
  1830 &  & \stackon{James Deere}{\tiny{(son)}} &  \\
  1840 & \stackon{Jane Doe}{\tiny{(daughter)}} &  &  \\
  1850 &  &  & Jack Johnson \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

As you can see, this causes the rows to be of different heights. I would like the relationship qualifiers to extend outside their row and into the row above. I'd prefer not to put them in the actual above cells.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Note you can define `\newcommand\relation[2]{\strut\smash{\stackon{#2}{\tiny{(#1)}}}}` and use it with an easier syntax as `\relation{daughter}{Jane Doe}`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up doing something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `\smash` the `\stack`ed-`on` construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\let\oldstackon\stackon

\renewcommand{\stackon}[2]{\strut\smash{\oldstackon{#1}{\tiny(#2)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r ccc }
  Year &              1               &           2                &      3       \\
  \hline
  1810 &          John Doe            &       John Deere           &  John Denver \\
  1820 &                              &                            &              \\
  1830 &                              & \stackon{James Deere}{son} &              \\
  1840 & \stackon{Jane Doe}{daughter} &                            &              \\
  1850 &                              &                            & Jack Johnson \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I've introduced some consistency-considerations for your use-case. If you *always* use a `\tiny(..)` setup for what is stacked on top, it's best to wrap this inside a macro.